# How can I make the font bigger, just between the first and second headings?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to use CSS to style everything between the first two headers in a `div`. E.g.:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>First</h1>
  <p>Big.</p>
  <p>Big.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Big.</li>
    <li>Big.</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Second</h2>
  <p>Normal.</p>
  <p>Normal.</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <h2>Third</h2>
  <p>Normal.</p>
  <p>Normal.</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I cannot change the HTML, so can't e.g. wrap the bigger stuff in another `<div>` or something like that. Best I can come up with so far is to enumerate the possibilities of elements following the first `<h1>` (for some number of elements) and make it bigger, e.g.:

```
#content h1:first-child + p,
#content h1:first-child + p + p,
#content h1:first-child + p + ul,
#content h1:first-child + p + p + ul,
...
{ font-size: larger; }
```

but this seems more tedious and fragile than it probably needs to be. What is a better way?

Comment: Will it always be an `h1` followed by an `h2`? Will it only be `p` and `ul` elements? This helps to narrow things down.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript to adjust things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Chromium (Ubuntu 11.04), the general sibling selector seems to achieve your aims:

```
h1 ~ * {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2,
h2 ~ * {
    font-size: 1em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A6yLS/1/).

This does, of course, *still* require knowledge of the underlying structure, but not quite so much, at least, as the adjacent sibling selectors you showed in your question.

---

As noted by @BoltClock, in comments, it might be wiser to avoid the `*` selector (for performance reasons) and instead use the `:not()` selector to identify the siblings:

```
h1 ~ :not(h2) {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 ~ :not(h2) {
    font-size: 1em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A6yLS/2/).

References:

- [CSS Selectors, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Comment: +1 Obligatory rant against using `*` as a key selector with combinators in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: In case you want to avoid styling subsequent `h2` elements, perhaps use `h2 ~ :not(h2)` in the second rule instead. Or to shut everyone up about `*`, just use both `h1 ~ :not(h2)` *and* `h2 ~ :not(h2)`. Or, you know, you can just... repeat the entire thing with `p`, `ul` and any other incidental element.

Comment: But seriously: `*` is frankly not all that slow. Even if it *were* slow, then `:not(h2)` will probably be almost equally slow. Most rants against the performance of the `*` selector are baseless, and the only people who should worry about such things are browser vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest my assumption is that you need to be super specific  (as you wrote in your question).  Otherwise you run the risk of these rules showing up elsewhere that it is not wanted.